# Get latest version number of the Google App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

I am writing a script to automatically download and update the installed version of the Google App Engine SDK. I can determine the installed version.

I currently need to make a wget request and check to see if it returns a 404 error; actually this is at least 2 requests, one to check for a bug fix update and a second to check for a minor version update.

I would like to avoid making these wget requests. To do this I need to determine the latest (stable not pre-release) version of the SDK. Is this info available via an API or other queryable source?

Comment: The python dev server does this already (check for latest release) have a look in the code at how they do it.

Comment: @TimHoffman I looked through the code for the dev_appserve.py as you suggested, but it uses the local VERSION file, which is how I am getting the installed version info. this is the comment from the code:   """Gets the version of the SDK by parsing the VERSION file.

Comment: But it checks what the current version on googles servers and if it is different to the currently installed version.  That check is what you want isn't it ?

Comment: @TimHoffman I didn't see it their, but I remembered that you can do a manual check from the windows launcher app. Checking the source for launcher I found the relevant method and URL http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck. If you want to type up an answer I will accept it and then delete my comments to clean up this question. the URL for the source is here: https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/source/browse/trunk/launcher/app.py.

Comment: I don't use the launcher.  When you run the dev_appserver from the command line it checks (unless you disable it) if the installed SDK is the most recent.  Will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python SDK checks for the current SDK when running the dev server.  The launcher also has this facility.

This would be the method I would use.

For the command line sdk the python code that implements the check is https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/sdk_update_checker.py  and as you pointed out the code for the launcher is https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/source/browse/trunk/launcher/app.py

The code performs an api RPC to http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck  and gets a yaml response.  So you can either use that code, or even just import and SDKUpdateChecker from sdk_checker.

Comment: Currently this does not work: the current AppEngine SDK version is 1.9.17, but the updatecheck URL returns 1.9.15. This version is however not longer available for download, making my script fail. Do you know any currently working solution (apart from scraping the URL out of the HTML of the website)?

Comment: The issue you mention was reported. There is no indication as to when, or if, it'll be fixed. You can read more on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11604.

I had to introduce a counterbug into https://github.com/rbanffy/appengine-fixture-loader and https://github.com/rbanffy/testable_appengine to unbreak the build.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has recently broken. http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck now returns a response like this with the latest release version set to 0.0.0:

```
$ curl -LSfs https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck
    release: "0.0.0"
    timestamp: 1586242881
    api_versions: ['1']
    supported_api_versions:
      python:
        api_versions: ['1']
      python27:
        api_versions: ['1']
      go:
        api_versions: ['go1', 'go1.9']
      java7:
        api_versions: ['1.0']
      go111:
        api_versions: [null]
```

The latest available version is `1.9.90` at
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.90.zip

It is possible that there will be future versions (1.9.91, etc.) provided at a similar URL, but that remains to be seen. It looks like `gcloud components install` and `gcloud components update` can be used to install the SDK, though it may be more difficult to script it.

UPDATE:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration

> As of July 30, 2019, the standalone App Engine SDK is deprecated. It will become unavailable for download on July 30, 2020.

`gcloud` is the way forward here, though I'm not sure of a good way to automate gcloud updates. If I find a good suggestion or come up with one, I'll update here.